# How to get Distinct keys of all child dictionary elements of all parent dictionary values

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this...
    `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, double>>`

How to get the list of all `Distinct` or `unique` child dictionary keys from all dictionaries of all parent dictionary values (parent dictionary values is nothing but child dictionaries)?

which is the fastest way of doing this in C#?

Comment: Have you tried anything already? Seems really easy using LINQ, but even if you don't know LINQ you can simply use a loop to get it done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really easy using LINQ:

```
var result = myDict.Values.SelectMany(x => x.Keys)
                          .Concat(myDict.Keys)
                          .Distinct()
                          .ToList();
```

but even without LINQ it's super easy when you use `HashSet<string>`:

```
var set = new HashSet<string>();

foreach(var outerItem in myDict)
{
    set.Add(outerItem.Key);
    foreach(var innerKey in item.Value.Keys)
    {
        set.Add(innerKey);
    }
}
```

`HashSet<T>` will only keep distinct items, so adding the same string twice won't make any difference.

PS. Next time you should try writing the code first, and ask question when you run into issue you can't overcome by yourself. Stack Overflow is not 'I want code, give me code' kind of site.

Comment: Sure i shall present the code from my next question. Sorry this is the first time in here.

Answer (score 1):

Then you need to call `SelectMany()` on `Values` property of your dictionary and then use `Distinct()` to get distinct elements from a sequence by using the default equality comparer.

```
 var res = myDict.Values.SelectMany(x => x.Keys).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: 1. You're missing keys from top level dictionary 2. You're missing `Distinct` call.

Comment: It works good! But i have to do a where clause filtering on Keys as well. Is there any way having it in the same LINQ query?

Comment: @prakash Yes, of course. Do you mean Keys in parent or child dictionaries?

Comment: Where clause should be applied on Keys of Child Dictionaries.

Comment: Sure Farhad!! Sorry this is first time i am here, so little confused on how to ask and follow up.

Comment: @prakash Not, problem. I have commented how to filter child keys. You can use for exampl this: `myDict.Values.SelectMany(x => x.Keys.Where(y=> y!= "Filter").ToList()).Distinct().ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

This code creates a Dictionary with string keys and double values.

```
    Dictionary<string, double> d = new Dictionary<string, double>()
    {           
    };
    // Store keys in a List
    List<string> list = new List<string>(d.Keys);
    // Loop through list
    foreach (string k in list)
    {
        //From here you can choose distinct key  
    }
```

Comment: It works! But i have to do a where clause filtering on Keys as well. Is there any way having it in the same LINQ query?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this right:

```
IEnumerable<string> uniqueChildKeys = dictOfDicts
   .SelectMany(d => d.Value.Keys)
   .Distinct();
```